# Game controller support in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, gamecontroller

We have a Xamarin.Forms game. We'd like to support game controller input from Razer Kishi on Android. Is it possible to achieve and if yes, how?

Also, as a follow-up question: Is it possible to have a cross-platform solution for game controller input over Android and iOS? If yes, how?

Comment: I'd guess that anything like this would need to be implemented per-platform.

Comment: Search `xamarin platform specific code`

Comment: Thanks, we'll have to see how it needs to be implemented but I guess it involves DependencyService.